# Not receiving in-app notifications of canceled/refunded purchases

Tags: android

I'm attempting to implement in-app billing using the [Android Billing Library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary). I've went through the static in-app responses, `android.test.purchased`, `android.test.canceled` and `android.test.refunded` and they all work properly.

Using my own product ids I confirmed that `PurchaseState.PURCHASED` works. As well as `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS`. And `PurchaseState.CANCELED` also works, but only if canceled before the order is charged. However, after an order is charged, if I cancel or refund a purchase, no in-app message is received.

I don't see any indication as to why in the logcat. Are these messages not sent until the actual refund is credited back, do they take awhile for some other reason (it's been almost 24 hours since I refunded a purchase on one of my test accounts and it still shows the purchase in-app), is it a testing thing or any ideas?